# Fatal Error when creating PHP PDO connection with msaccess using ODBC

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc, wamp

For some reasons i need to use ms-access in my PHP application therefore I have enable `php_pdo_odbc` extension in WAMP. Which shows in `phpinfo()`

But i am unable to connect the database, it returns the following error.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified' in
>   C:\wamp64\www...\portals...\config.php on line 15
>
> ( ! )> PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0
>   [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified in C:\wamp64\www...\portals...\config.php on line 15

```
$db_username = ''; //username
$db_password = ''; //password

//path to database file
$database_path = "StudentLogInData.mdb";

//check file exist before we proceed
if (!file_exists($database_path)) {
    die("Access database file not found !");
}

//create a new PDO object
$database = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=realpath($database_path); Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password;");
```

I'm using WAMP 64bit version on Windows 7 (64-Bit). Searched alot of Stackoverflow's solutions for example tried running 32 bit version but it can't be installed on 64 bit. Please help how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[realpath()](http://php.net/realpath) is a PHP function, not something that the ODBC driver understands. You possibly want to remove it from the DSN:

```
$database_path = realpath("StudentLogInData.mdb");
$database = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$database_path; Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password;");
```

As about the driver name, you need to type ODBC in your *Start* menu and verify the given name is available in your *Drivers* tab:

[image: ODBC Manager]

Comment: Done. but same error and also tried full path in the DSN string but same error as well. I'm feeling this has to be something with 64-bit version.

Comment: Well, sorry, I had assumed you had already installed the driver that provides "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)": https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I have installed it and rebooted the machine but still same error. And i checked the drivers tab i dont have MS Access listed. screenshot http://imgur.com/a/l4hCL

Comment: Then it clearly didn't install successfully. PHP won't be able to use the driver until it's available.

Comment: But i installed the drivers from your link. What could be done now?

Comment: There're two downloads in that site. You installed the 64-bit ones, didn't you?

Comment: I did 64-bit First, it didn't installed because I have office 32-bit version. Then i installed 32-bit drivers which installed successfully.

Comment: Did this actually fix your issue? I am having same error but I see the right driver in the drivers of ODBC..